# php upload file restrictions

Tags: php, upload

Im trying to limit my upload to only upload file extensions with a pdf.
I've previously got the upload working but with any extension using ;

```
$form = $_FILES['form']['name'];
$upload = "forms/$form";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['form']['tmp_name'],$upload);
```

I'm now trying to adjust this to only upload pdf, Using the following;

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']))
    $exten = explode( "." , $_FILES['form']['name']);
    $exten = $exten[1];
    $form = $_FILES['form']['name'];
    $upload = "forms/$form";

    if (
        ($exten == "pdf")
    ||  ($exten == "PDF")){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['form']['tmp_name'] , $upload);

    }
```

However the files are not uploading to the directory anymore plus it accepts any extension. It is entering the filename within my database.
I followed a tutorial for this but not sure where I've gone wrong

Comment: This approach would give you a false sense of success for names like for example `somefile.pdf.ugly`.

Comment: In general is it questionable if such a check does make _any_ sense. A "file name extension" is something that can be set arbitrary. It is a leftover from an area long gone. If you want to limit file types, then check the file type, not the file name extension.

Comment: Why `isset($_FILES['file'])`?

Comment: @arkascha thanks for pointing that one out, just noticed I'd named it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get file extension try [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) with PATHINFO_EXTENSION parameter, it will save you time

You should also use [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) function to make a comparison because for example .PdF/.PDf extensions will be unexpectedly rejected by the condition you wrote

```
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $exten = pathinfo($_FILES['form']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $form = $_FILES['form']['name'];
    $upload = "forms/$form";

    if (strtolower($exten) == 'pdf'){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['form']['tmp_name'] , $upload);

    }
}
```

PS: **did you miss brackets** after isset function or is just a copy-paste issue?

Comment: thanks, it doesn't upload the files to the directory if not pdf, but still writes the filename to the database. but I'm halfway there, so thankyou

Comment: Try using a static path, just to check if you yours is a permission issue or a path issue

Comment: I mean for like a .php file - it doesn't get uploaded which is correct but it still writes hello.php within the database column

Answer (score 1):

You can check file type this way:

```
if ($_FILES['form']['type'] == 'application/pdf') {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['form']['tmp_name'] , $_FILES['form']['name']);
}
```

`$_FILES['form']['type']` contains MIME type of uploaded file

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php